# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used...//

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

this is the code where I also have this error, more precisely in the line with **trackColor: isDarkMode? Colors.white : Colors.grey,** I don't know exactly what the problem would be, this code is for a settings_page.dart in my application, and in the settings page I have a theme dark switch, but when I press it, nothing happens

```
Padding buildNotificationOption(
    String title, bool value, Function onChangeMethod) {
  final isDarkMode =
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);

  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 20),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.grey[600],
          ),
        ),
        Transform.scale(
          scale: 0.7,
          child: CupertinoSwitch(
            activeColor: Colors.blue,
            trackColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
            value: value,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              onChangeMethod(newValue);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

i tried, i tried

Comment: What type is inferred for "isDarkMode"?  I suspect it's "void", since that function likely doesn't return anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

`SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle()` is a void method. Since it is setter method, it doesn't return any value.

So, you can't assign its result to `isDarkMode`. Instead you need to use a boolean or method that returns a boolean.